# Tornado blocking during real-time feed

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado

In my tornado application I'll be having users accessing my database and requesting data. As my application is doing real-time analysis from this data each client will be connecting to the database for very long periods of time. Thus this would make the application blocking?

So If I use AsyncMongo would that solve this problem and make the application non-blocking? I want simultaneous users to use the application? Otherwise each client could be blocking for minutes whilst they use the app.

The Handler that connect the client to the mongodb in the server is a websocket.

Would I use the @web.asynchronous the gen decorator as well? Or is it better to use multiprocessing?

I'm very new to this so have no experience in either, but would be looking at the easiest to pick up and implement?

It would be great to see some example/ tutorial code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*>make the application blocking?*

Roughly what makes your application blocking is the framework you use: Django is blocking. Tornado is non blocking.

*> AsyncMongo*

This is an Async db driver but it is old and hasn't been updated for some time. Using it makes your DB calls asynchronous. But it might well be better to use the synchronous [PyMongo](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver) as it is maintained by the 10gen people and make sure your queries return quickly. There is a new experimental async library for python called [Motor](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/motor-asynchronous-mongodb)

*>@web.asynchronous the gen decorator as well*

The gen is a way of making your async queries easier to read. It is nothing to do with multiprocessing

*>Architecture & Blocking*

If you keep reading and feeding the data back to the client then yes it will block. Either

1. Dont use Tornado
2. Change your architecture so the connection isn't kept open
3. Use an async driver like AsyncMongo or Motor

Comment: Thanks for your response...As I'm using PyMongo one client can access the database but then it seems the app is being blocked when trying to open another client browser. I'm using tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler to keep the connection open and data is constantly read from mongodb and sent to client. So if I use 'Motor' then would this prevent the problem? As PyMongo doesn't let me do this.

Comment: I think I'm going to try and use the Motor driver for Mongo...It seems to now have most of the functionality of pymongo, so hopefully will be straightforward to incorporate. I think the problem with my application and generally using Tornado is that eventhough Tornado is non-blocking if you use a library that is not non-blocking eg.PyMongo then it makes this aspect of Tornado redundant.